# Trying Backbone.js, my collection object doesn't loads the data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i am using Backbone.js and the server part is a Rest service written in Java using Jax-RS,

the response which i get from server is as follows,

```
{
"student":[
        {"collegeName":"Hollywood Inc.","id":"12","name":"Jim Carry","salary":"100"},
        {"collegeName":"Hollywood Inc.","id":"13","name":"Nicholas Cage","salary":"400"},
        {"collegeName":"Hollywood Inc.","id":"14","name":"Edi Murphy","salary":"567"},
        {"collegeName":"Hollywood Inc.","id":"15","name":"Will Smith","salary":"500"},
        {"collegeName":"Hollywood Inc.","id":"16","name":"Jack Nicholsan","salary":"234"}
        ]
}
```

Now my client side  backbone.js code is as follows,

```
var fn01 = function(){
try{
window.Student = Backbone.Model.extend();

window.StudentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student,
    url: "http://localhost:8081/rest/firstRest/demo/get",
    parse: function(response){            
        var studentArray = new Array();
        _.each(response.student,function(std){
            (function(student){
                studentArray.push(new Student({id: student.id, name: student.name}));                    
            })(std);                
        });
        this.models = studentArray;
        return this.models;
    }
});

window.StudentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName: "ul",

   initialize: function(){
       this.model.on("reset",this.render,this);
   },

   render: function(evt){
       _.each(this.model.models, function(student){
           $(this.el).append(new StudentListItemView({model: student}).render().el);
       },this);
       return this;           
   }
});

window.StudentListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",

    template: _.template($("#tpl-student-list-item").html()),

    render: function(evt){
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({        
    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },        
    list: function(){          
      this.studentList = new StudentCollection();
      this.studentListView = new StudentListView({model: this.studentList});          
      this.studentList.fetch();  
      $("#sidebar").html(this.studentListView.render().el);
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();     
Backbone.history.start();


}catch(e){
   alert(" ERROR "+e);
} 

}

onLoadFn(fn01);
```

the response which i get is a json object of students,
here what i am trying to do is on page load fetch the students from server and store it in the StudentCollection object.
the studentCollection object has a property "models", which gives a array of Student Object.

But in my case the models property of studentCollection object is empty array.

hence i added a method parse in StudentCollection and explicitly made models assigned to array,

but still my studentList.models is an [] i.e. empty array,

Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: Why don't you just return `response.student` in the `parse` method of the collection ? Models will be generated based on the return value from the parse. And there's no need to do `$("#sidebar").html(this.studentListView.render().el)` in the `AppRouter`. Are the `#sidebar` and tagName `ul` specified in `StudentListView` same ?

Comment: #sidebar is a div, and i am trying to create ul and li inside div, so to display list of students

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you name `collection` as collection and not as `model`. If you're directly calling the `render` from outside, then it defeats the purpose of binding collection's `reset` event in the `StudentListView`. What elements are present in the `dom` when the app is initialized ?

Comment: <h3>Student-List</h3>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
        <script type="text/template" id="tpl-student-list-item">
            <a href='#student/<%= id %>'><%= name %></a>
        </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be, you can specify the `ul` initially in the `dom` like:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Just return the `response.student` from the collection parse:

```
window.StudentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  // ... existing code

  parse: function(response){            
    return response.student;
  }
});
```

And StudentListView as:

```
window.StudentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // change tagName to el
  el: "#sidebar ul",

  // ... existing code
});
```

And the `AppRouter` as:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({        
  // ... existing code     

  list: function(){          
    this.studentList = new StudentCollection();
    this.studentListView = new StudentListView({collection: this.studentList});          
    this.studentList.fetch();
  }
});
```

And another approach could be, don't bind `reset` event of the collection as:

```
window.StudentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ... existing code

  initialize: function(){
    // this.model.on("reset",this.render,this); .. don't bind this event
  },
});
```

And `AppRouter` as:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({        
  // ... existing code

  list: function(){
    // ... existing code
    var _this = this;          
    this.studentList.fetch({
      success: function() {
        $("#sidebar").html(_this.studentListView.render().el);  
      },
      error: function() {

      }
    });  
  }
});
```